# MySQL update fatal error on AWS Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apt

I was just browsing the system logs on my alestic Ubuntu 10.04 AWS EC2 production server, and found this:

```
daemon.log.1:Dec  9 22:45:42 server1 /etc/mysql/debian-start[865]: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
daemon.log.1:Dec  9 22:45:42 server1 /etc/mysql/debian-start[865]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I'm assuming it came from a routine `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Is this something I need to address? It looks serious.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you deleted the debian-sys-maint user, or the password for this user needs to be reset.  The init scripts use this account for stopping/starting and maintanence.  It expects the password for this account to match the password found in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.  The user is typically created having all privileges.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there some way (once I've fixed the debian-sys-maint account) to re-run the upgrade process?

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a` will configure any packages remaining to be configured.  `apt-get -f install` will "fix" any broken dependencies if any were left over from the failed upgrade.  I'd not expect broken packages, but it should never be harmful to run.